# socket.io not working on Heroku on React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, heroku

I am having an issue with socket.io working on local host, but not when deployed to heroku.

on the client side I have this:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const socket = socketIOClient("http://127.0.0.1:4001");
```

and on the server side:

```
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server);

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  socket.on("chat message", function(msg) {
    console.log("message: " + msg);
    io.emit("chat message", msg);
  });
```

This works perfectly on local host, but on Heroku it throws CORS errors. To combat that, I have tried changing this line:

```
const socket = socketIOClient("http://127.0.0.1:4001");
```

to

```
const socket = socketIOClient("https://radiant-retreat-86258.herokuapp.com/");
```

(that is the URL of the app).

I have also tried changing the code to this:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io();
```

both those options take away the CORS error, however the network is showing continuous 403's, and the socket doesn't actually do what it should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cors()` npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors